# Do I need to fill out an AR-11, if my address is the same as I get my Social Security to?

Tags: usa, greencard

After having moved to the United States, I've camped around the Bay area for 6 months, using Airbnb, and trying out different living conditions. Throughout these time, I haven't completed an AR-11, due to not having a stable place of residence.

I have now found a place to crash long-term; I've been living here for 3 months. I have filled out the forms to arrange for my NI; they've posted it to this specific address. Does it mean they have this as my permanent resident address, or do I have to fill out an AR-11?

What are the consequences for late filing?

If this is required, what should I put under "old address"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fill AR-11 within 10 days after moving. It has nothing to do with Social Security whatsoever, different agency entirely.

Comment: And how is the day of moving determined?

Comment: @s.brody the day of the moving generally determined by having a whole bunch of underpaid over-trained in heavy lifting dudes in your old place taking your stuff into a truck that then will get that stuff to your new place.